# MPI Can you find the IP address of all the individual nodes?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I was wondering if it was possible? To get the ip addresses of all the individual ranks using MPI4PY. I realize I can use sockets and have a signal sent. I am just curious if there is a built in function that will do this for me. Mainly just if something goes wrong with sockets getting the IP address which happens sometimes.

Comment: Keep in mind a node can have multiple IP addresses (besides the obvious `localhost`). A portable way of getting one IP address per node is to use the standard `MPI_Get_processor_name()` subroutine, `MPI_Gather()` the host names, and then convert host names to IP.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet `MPI_Get_processor_name()` is not guaranteed to return an IP address or a host name, so I wouldn't call that portable.

Comment: That’s a fair point!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of MPI is to hide the details of the underlying communication subsystem such as IP addresses under the abstraction of communicators and process ranks. There are no provisions in the MPI specification for disclosing such information in a portable way.

The closest you can get is [`MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME`](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node210.htm#Node215), which returns a string identifier of the piece of hardware that the caller is running on. Most MPI implementations targeting clusters of individual nodes return the node hostname, which in theory could be resolved to an IP, but that's not guaranteed since many systems have more than one hostname, e.g., an internal one (on Linux, the one set with `sethostname(2)`) and a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) that can be resolved to an IP.

The standard says nothing specific about the contents of this string and each implementation is free to choose what to return. For example, on Blue Gene/Q, `MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME` returns the task number, job size, and logical and physical coordinates of the rank in the communication grid:

```
"Task 3 of 256 (0,0,0,0,1,1)  R02-M1-N00-J07"
```